# calling different package and choosing the correct one

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

I have to switch from first apk to second apk and that i have done successfully. But the problem is I have to choose between multiple package. If the package is correct then application should switch. So for that i tried to put multiple package names in string and calling in intent but it is going in else part only.

The code snippet is:

i initialise a string variable

```
String value="com.android.example";
```

and passing here in intent

```
intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(value);
```

When I run the apk, it is not accepting the any value even the correct package and going in else part. Please give me suggestions for the same and kindly let me know if i can do the same through any other method.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: The question is simple as that I have to choose the correct package between multiple packages using if else and if the package chosen is correct then the further action should be done.But i am getting the problem in choosing the correct package because through package manager I am only able to know the current apk package. How that it can identify the other package name installed on device? So this is the prob and I am not able to identify

Answer (score 0):

Use PackageManager to check if packages you look for do exist on this device and then act accordingly to the results you obtained from the check.

Comment: yes i have checked through package manager also. But not working

Comment: the prob is it is not recognising the package.

Comment: Well, I quite doubt so and suspect you doing something wrong (or I missed your point). Show your code. If your package is there, you installed it w/o any troubles, then I see no reason PackageManager can't see it. That'd be odd, as PackageManager was already involved when you installed the package

Comment: yes that needed for the testing purpose. So i got the solution that now i an entering package name in edit text and if it is correct then it can invoke the other application. Now its working fine.